# How to implement ScrollView in kv language?

Tags: python, scrollview, handler, kivy

How can i implement this code in the kv language?

```
layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10,
        size_hint=(None, None), width=500)

layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
```

in particular i need to implement some *widgets* (buttons,labels) within a **ScrollView** similar to this line of code:

```
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
```

This piece of code was taken by the *scrollview.py* example shipped with the kivy framework. I'd like to do the same thing showed in that example but all in the .kv file. Is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python code would look like this in KV.

```
ScrollView:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: None, None
        width: 500
        height: self.minimum_height
```

You'll need to make sure that your ScrollView has a layout widget that supports the `minimum_height` property (for vertical scrolling). Buttons and widgets should then go in that layout.

Comment: `BoxLayout` doesn't have a `minimum_height` property so I think you'd need to set the height of the `BoxLayout` manually. You are, of course, free to put a `BoxLayout` in your `GridLayout`.